# Outputting rows from the pg module in Node / Postgres

Tags: postgresql, node.js

In my Node app, I want to connect to a postgresql database to do some work on the entities.  But I am having trouble getting it to work with Node.  I have successfully connected and queried the database from a Python script with psycopg2, so I know that the connection part can work.

```
var DB_URL = "postgres://admin@localhost/mydb_development"
var db = new pg.Client(DB_URL);
db.connect();

.... more stuff here ....    


app.get('/test', function(request, response) {
  response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  response.write("First!\n");
  var i = 0;
  var query = db.query("SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'public'", []);
  query.on('row', function(row) {
    console.log(row['table_name']);
    i++;
    response.write(String(row['table_name']) + "\n");
  });
  response.write("\nHello db; variable i=" + i + "!");
  response.end();
});
```

I am finding that the console.log(row['table_name']) is successfully outputting the table names to the console.  However, it looks like neither the response variable nor i are available inside the closure... then how the heck am I supposed to get the results of the query to do stuff with it?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`response` variable is available but not writeable, as you already `end`ed it.
`i` should also be available, but at the time you're writing it to the response, it has not been increased yet.

You probably wanted to `end` it (and to write the final line) after you've got all the rows. It could be achieved like this:

```
var DB_URL = "postgres://admin@localhost/mydb_development"
var db = new pg.Client(DB_URL);
db.connect();

.... more stuff here ....    


app.get('/test', function(request, response) {
  response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  response.write("First!\n");
  var i = 0;
  var query = db.query("SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'public'", []);
  query.on('row', function(row) {
    console.log(row['table_name']);
    i++;
    response.write(String(row['table_name']) + "\n");
  });
  query.on('end', function () {
      response.write("\nHello db; variable i=" + i + "!");
      response.end();
  });
});
```

Comment: Oh, so it's asynchronous! Makes sense now! Is there a way to say "I want JS to wait until it ends"... maybe use a for loop that waits until a variable in 'end' is set? Lots of asynchronous code is the new spaghetti code.

Comment: You can use libraries such as async to make your asynchronous code less spaghetti-similar. If you would turn this code into a synchronous one (e.g. with a for loop as you suggest), the server would be unable to serve several requests simultaneously, which will result in an unacceptable performance.